# How to use foreach loop on list except elements at some index?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am having foreach loop on List like:

```
foreach( var e in myList){

//do something here but except  element at myList[0]

}
```

and now I need to omit the loop for the element at first index. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foreach(var e in myList.Skip(1)){

}
```

Comment: Yes,exactly. Thanks for your help @Ivan Crojach

Comment: Great! Just don't forget to mark it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to skip elements at arbitrary indexes using `for` would be more appropriate:

```
for(var index = 0; index < myList.Count; index++){
     if (ShouldSkip(index))
          continue;
     // handle other elements as normal
}
```

If you need to skip just first - use .Skip(1) as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884993/477420

If you want to use `foreach` with arbitrary indexes you can filter with `.Where`:

```
 foreach(var e in myList.Where((item, index) => index < 3 || index > 7))
 {
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as well try to use this:

```
foreach(var item in itemsList.Except(itemsToOmitList)){}
```

The good thing with using the above approach is that you will be able to omit multiple items irrespective of their index.